# Drag and MouseDown conflicts

Tags: delphi, select, listbox, mouse

I have a a listbox with DragMode set to `dmAutomatic` to drag the item's text elsewhere.

I have Multiselect set to `true`. I want to be able to click and drag over my listbox items to select in sequence multiple rows. So I have:

```
Shift := [ssLeft];
```

in the `ListBoxMouseDown` event. Dragging for multiselect is not working. If I physically hold down the shift key while I click and drag, I get the desired outcome. Any suggestions on why or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this the wrong way. Don't use `DragMode=dmAutomatic` at all, it is not meant for how you are trying to use it.  Instead, in the `OnMouseDown` event, set a flag when the left button is down.  In the `OnMouseMove` event, select the current item under the mouse if the flag is set. In the `OnMouseUp` event, clear the flag.  For example:

```
var
  Dragging: Boolean = False;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  If Button = mbLeft then
    Dragging := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  If Button = mbLeft then
    Dragging := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  If not Dragging then Exit;
  Index := ListBox1.ItemAtPos(Point(X, Y), True): Integer;
  If Index <> -1 then
    ListBox1.Selected[Index] := True;
end;
```